# Generate arrays with random numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, random

I need to create an array (observations) which contains arrays of eight numbers (named observation). These numbers should be in range between 0 and 9.

```
let observations = [];
let observation = [];
let min = 0;
let max = 9;
for (let i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        observation[j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    observations.push(observation);
}
```

Problem: The numbers are pseudo random and I get the same result 20 000 times.

Is there a possibility to fix this issue in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reusing the same `observation` array each time, but simply overwriting it in the inner loop. So all the references to it contain the results from the last iteration.

You need to create a new `observation` array each time through the outer loop.

```
let observations = [];
let min = 0;
let max = 9;
for (let i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
    let observation = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        observation.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);
    }
    observations.push(observation);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could move the empty array inside of the first level, because you keep the same object reference.

```
let observations = [];
let min = 0;
let max = 9;
for (let i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
    let observation = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        observation[j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    observations.push(observation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.seed = function(s) {
    return function() {
        s = Math.sin(s) * 10000; return s - Math.floor(s);
    };
};

let observations = [];
let observation = [];
let min = 0;
let max = 9;
for (let i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getMilliseconds();
    for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        observation[j] = Math.floor(Math.seed(i+j+n)() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    observations.push(observation);
    observation = [];
}

JSON.stringify(observations);
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional solution:

```js
const observations = Array.from({length: 20000}, () => 
  Array.from({length: 10}, () => (Math.random() * 10 | 0)))
```